# Unknown number of function parameters c++

Tags: c++, function, parameters

For example, I need to count the average of 3, 5, 10 or more numbers (I don't know the exact number with the function like:

```
double average(/* Unknown number of parameters here */) {

}
```

So, I need the way to count the number and sum of parameters. I'm very new to c++ and I will appreciate any help.

Comment: Use a `std::vector` as an argument?

Comment: You could store the numbers in a `std::vector`: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can code like this. Here is the details : http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_variable_arguments.htm

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdarg.h>

double average(int num,...)
{

    va_list valist;
    double sum = 0.0;
    int i;


    va_start(valist, num); // initialize valist



    for (i = 0; i < num; i++)
    {
       sum += va_arg(valist, int);
    }

    va_end(valist); // clean memory

    return sum/num;
}

int main()
{
   printf("Average of 2, 3, 4, 5 = %f\n", average(4, 2,3,4,5));
   printf("Average of 5, 10, 15 = %f\n", average(3, 5,10,15));
}
```

Comment: Welcome , but I recommend You should understand everything clearly by googling.. :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use an initializer list.

```
double average(std::initializer_list<int> i){...}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution based on variadic templates. Advantage: no need to specify number of arguments.

```
double sum(double value)
{
  return value;
}

template<typename... Rest>
double sum(double first, Rest... rest)
{
  return first + sum(rest...);
}

template<typename... Args>
double average(Args... args)
{
  return sum(args...) / sizeof...(Args);
}
```

Comment: this is the only correct answer in all three proposed. I don't understand why it's been downvoted.